# Is it possible to apply rules to a file type but not another in .editorconfig

Tags: editorconfig

I want to apply rules in my .editorconfig file to all c# files like so...

```
[*.cs]
```

but I want those rules NOT to apply to .xaml.cs files.  So what I want is something like this

```
[*.cs|!*.xaml.cs]
```

But the above doesn't work.  Is there any way to do this?